# Convert pixel array to DNG in SWIFT ... without libtiff/libjpeg?

Tags: swift, image, adobe, raw, dng

I have raw image data, a pixel array (actually a single string of data) that I want to convert to the most basic and minimal DNG format/file. I saw different approaches utilizing libtiff and libjpeg.

Is there a simpler and more straight forward way to do this in SWIFT using Core Graphics, Core Image or yet another SWIFT API?

The image data are still in the original Bayer matrix format (CFA pattern is RGGB) without any tags.

I downloaded the over 100 pages of the latest Adobe DNG format specification, but I cannot find the actual byte order or structure of the DNG file in there... I am pretty lost with this document.

Any help and hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: DNG is a tagged image data format similar to TIFF. One may follow these explanations to generate DNG/TIFF raw images that could then be read by the CIFilter as raw image data:
http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/tiff/tiff_summary.pdf